# Style input type = text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor with background icon which is nice styled. I would like to use it as if user clicks on it choose file window appear.

Simple input type = text doesn't look nice for me. Is it possible to hide it and control appearance of browse windows from my anchor?

Thanks for any help, solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do much with it, but you can get around that limitation quite easily by making the box invisible and triggering it via other elements.

Here are a few implementations (I like the first one):

- http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload
- http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
- http://creativefan.com/10-ajax-jquery-file-uploaders/